# EF Core set Id to Int.MinValue and try to insert in database

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core and I have a problem when I save a new entity.

Here is my model class

```
[Column("Id")]
public int ID { get; set; }
[Required]
[Column("Pratica", TypeName = "varchar(10)")]
public string PRATICA { get; set; }
[Column("Anno")]
public int ANNO { get; set; }
[Required]
[Column("Variante", TypeName = "varchar(2)")]
public string VARIANTE { get; set; }
```

Here I create and initialize a new PRAT object:

```
var prat = new PRAT();
prat.PRATICA = "Prova";
prat.ANNO = 2000;
prat.VARIANTE = "0";
context.PRAT.Add(prat);
context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Just after the context.PRAT.Add(prat) line if I check prat.ID member I get something like -2147482647

After context.SaveChangesAsync I get the error "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Prat' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF"

This is the generated SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO [Prat] ([Id], [Anno], [Pratica], [Variante]) VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3);
```

As you can see the Id Field is added to the list of fields, but this field is Identity!

If, before context.SaveChangesAsync() I set

```
prat.ID = 0
```

the generated SQL Statement is

```
INSERT INTO [Prat] ([Anno], [Pratica], [Variante]) VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2);
```

And all works fine.

Thank you.

Comment: are you using migrations?

Comment: This works fine for me. (exact above code). Which version of EF Core are you using?

Comment: Sorry I'm late.
I don't use migration and I am using version 1.1.2 of EF Core.
Thank you

Comment: @user7817808 EF Core version information is critical for such issues. Even if that was an issue in earlier EF Core, it should have been fixed a long time ago.

Comment: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.1, at least in my case

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to configure your model with the [DatabaseGenerated](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/databasegenerated-attribute) attribute, or configure it with [fluent api](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/valuegeneratedonadd-method)

```
...
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[Column("Id")]
public int ID { get; set; }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The primary key property is of type int, by convention EF Core assumes that the database will use the SQL
IDENTITY command to create a unique key when a new row is added. So you must define your database column as [identity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GdqGeaTfduc) column.

Comment: According to the exception message, the database column is already identity - *"Cannot insert explicit value for **identity column** in table 'Prat' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF"*

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still dealing with this, the other answers are insufficient. Primary keys for ints, shorts, guids etc in EF core are automatically generated.

The DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity is for columns that are not primary keys.

The real problem is that somewhere in your code (potentially your database seeder if you have one) is pushing entities with manually entered primary keys.
For example:

```
_context.Jobs.Add(
           new Job()
                {
                    JobId = 1,
                    Name = "Truck Driver",
                },

            );
            _context.SaveChanges();
```

Doing so tells ef core that you will be supplying primary keys for that entity and it will not know how to generate them. I am unsure why this is because you would think ef core could just grab the max value primary key and add 1 but I think the PK value generation code under the hood is the same for all primary key datatypes (including guid where max value isn't a thing).

Anyways, remove the code where you are manually inserting primary keys and the Add functionality should work as expected.